# Battery charging notification

Tags: android

Can we receive notification if phone battery is start charging? Whether power source is an AC charger or USB cable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can listen for the [ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED) broadcast and check the power details using BATTERY_PLUGGED_[AC/USB] (Check details [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager.html)).