# Android: Detect when ADB active over USB

Tags: android, adb

Is it possible to have an application detect when ADB is listening over USB on an Android phone?

I'm looking for something like this: [Is it possible to determine whether an Android device is plugged into a computer or just power?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641511/is-it-possible-to-determine-whether-an-android-device-is-plugged-into-a-computer) but specifically for when ADB is running.

Thanks!

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/a/7156252/2114852

Comment: Good reference, but note that charging doesn't necessarily mean ADB - it might mean a charger.  Also, is it important to differentiate between being connected to a PC without an SDK, vs one with the SDK and an active ADB server on the PC, vs one where there's an active channel open through ADB to a shell, logcat, push/pull operation, port forward, etc ?

Comment: I don't need to check if ADB is running on the computer as I don't thing that is possible. Just that the ADB service is running on the phone and listening over USB. Basically whenever the ADB notification is displayed.

Answer (score 4):

```
Settings.Global.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.ADB_ENABLED, 0);
```

Will return a 1 if USB Debugging is enabled on the phone and a 0 if it isn't.

Comment: this checks whether USB Debugging is enabled on the phone or not. Not detecting current ADB connected device.

Comment: above answer is good.  is the above code will work for detect wireless debug mode ?